# clearcase see when was the stream last rebased

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I have the below stream in clearcase

```
[tthangavel@wtl-lbuild-4 fw]$ c lsstream
2016-05-23T03:32:31-04:00  my_stream_name  user1
```

How do I check when was the stream last updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view is updated, a stream is rebased.

You can check the minor events associated to its history ([`cleartool lshistory`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm)):

```
cleartool lshist -min stream:tcp_540_svcommon@\mypvob
```

(replace `mypvob` by the PVob or project vob of that stream, note: `/vobs/mypvob` on Unix `\mypvob` on Windows)

If that doesn't work, all you can do is check the date of the foundation baselines (using [`fmt_ccase`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm)):

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%[found_bls]CXp" stream:tcp_540_svcommon@\mypvob
```

For each baseline, check its date: the most recent is the last rebase.

Comment: Thanks @VonC, the second command helps somewhat (because of the baseline names), but still can't be sure when was the actual rebase done :(

Answer (score 0):

The lshist -minor will tell you, if the data has not been scrubbed. But it's not pretty. lshistory -minor will tell you everything involved with the rebase, including removing and recreating the baseline hyperlinks.

Here is the lshistory -minor output of a new rebase:

```
C:\Users\bcowan.DEV>cleartool lshist -min stream:bcowan_Test_Project_mid@\projects
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     set process variable on activity "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Set activity process variable named "UCM_REBASE_MISC"."
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     set process variable on activity "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Set activity process variable named "UCM_REBASE"."
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     change stream "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Updated config_spec.
   Regenerated config spec"
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     set process variable on activity "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Set activity process variable named "SUM_CSPEC_ID"."
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     make hyperlink "UseBaseline" on activity "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Attached hyperlink "UseBaseline@22347@\projects"."
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     remove hyperlink "UseBaseline" from activity "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Removed hyperlink "UseBaseline@562@\projects"."
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     set process variable on activity "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Set activity process variable named "UCM_REBASE"."
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     set process variable on activity "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Set activity process variable named "UCM_REBASE"."
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     set process variable on activity "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Set activity process variable named "UCM_REBASE"."
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     set process variable on activity "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Set activity process variable named "UCM_REBASE"."
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     set process variable on activity "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Set activity process variable named "UCM_REBASE"."
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     set process variable on activity "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Set activity process variable named "UCM_REBASE"."
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     set process variable on activity "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Set activity process variable named "UCM_REBASE"."
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     set process variable on activity "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Set activity process variable named "UCM_REBASE"."
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     set process variable on activity "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Set activity process variable named "UCM_REBASE_MISC"."
--08-29T16:02  bcowan     set process variable on activity "bcowan_Test_Project_mid"
  "Set activity process variable named "UCM_REBASE"."
```

This is a SINGLE component update rebase.

How long this data stays in the VOB is controlled by the vob_scrubber_params file (see the "vob_scrubber" man page). The default is to keep all this event data for up to 7 days, and the last on a given stream for 30 days.